# JQuery SmartWizard - JQuery-Pluggin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, smart-wizard

I am using following control to design a wizard in JQuery:

http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation

By Default it shows three buttons (properties) labelNext, labelPrevious, labelFinish

As per requirement I would like to add another button So we can have buttons like

Previous, Next, Save, Save & Publish.

I see no option to add custom button

I want new button as below:

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Download bellow zip file and use that js and css

[Download Zip](http://www.files.com/shared/53ea0420db4fd/SmartWizard.zip)

Comment: which version it is? I need to run it on IE8 so only looking for version which required jquery  1.x. does it support custom buttons?

Comment: i haven't updated jquery, only edited jquery.smartWizard-2.0.min.js

Comment: It break my existing code. Not showing contents inside the tabs.  I need something as below: Add new Label which should turn into button as other three buttons: labelNext: "Next", labelPrevious: "Previous", labelFinish: "Finish", 

labelSaveAndFinish: "SaveAndFinish", onLeaveStep: null, onShowStep: null, onFinish: null

Answer (score 0):

The latest version have option to add more button to the toolbar. Here is the example [Smart Wizard: Demo](http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/demo/basic) and the [Smart Wizard: Documentaion](http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation#paramdesc)